# Doctrine2 - How to include the last day of the month in this query

Tags: date, symfony, datetime, doctrine-orm

Can someone point out what is missing in this query? The last day of the month does not appear.

Have tried using (->where('b.created >= :start'), ->andWhere('b.created <= :end') instead of the BETWEEN but that didn't work.

```
public function getPostsByMonth($year, $month)
{
$date = new \DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-01");

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b');
$query = $qb
    ->where('b.created BETWEEN :start AND :end')
    ->setParameter('start', $date->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->setParameter('end', $date->modify('last day of this month')->format('Y-m-d'))
;
return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

**Changes**

```
    $date = new \DateTime("{$year}-{$month}-01");
    $toDate = clone $date;
    $toDate->modify("last day of this month");

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('b')
        ->where('b.created BETWEEN :start AND :end')
        ->setParameter('start', $date)
        ->setParameter('end', $toDate);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen the actual query executed on the database?

It seems that you are using the same DateTime; when you do a $date->modify(), it does not return a new object, instead it changes it's internal data, but it remains the same instance.

Also, when you ask the DateTime object to go to the `last day of this month`, you end up in `YYYY-01-31 00:00:00` which is effectively one day before the end of the month. Change your time string so it goes to the first day of the next month at midnight, which is exactly where you want to be: `YYYY-02-01 00:00:00`:

```
$toDate = clone $date;
$toDate->modify("first day of next month midnight");
```

Also, you don't need to format it, you can pass directly the DateTime object and let Doctrine do the hard work under the hood:

```
$query = $qb
    ->where('b.created BETWEEN :start AND :end')
    ->setParameter('start', $date)
    ->setParameter('end', $toDate)
;
```

Comment: Made changes as shown above, and the last day of the month still doesn't appear.

Comment: Try `$toDate->modify("first day of next month midnight");`

Comment: Bingo! That did the trick, thank you Alberto for answer and suggestions on improvement. Can you edit your answer?

Comment: Done! Added more detailed explanation.